# How do I fire an event whenever a list is added to?

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a `List` containing `structs`. I would like to fire an event every time the `List` has been added to. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than `List<T>`.

The `CollectionChanged` event will fire whenever an item is added or removed from the collection .

Comment: Perfect. I will muck with this for a while before accepting the answer. Thank you.

Comment: `ObservableCollection<T>` seems to be for WPF specifically. I think I need to use `BindingList<T>`.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron Do you intend to use this List as data source for a Windows Forms control? What type of control?

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_

Comment: @MickyD By all means, enlighten me as to what makes this a bad question. I didn't give code examples because it's a simple enough question to understand without it. By omitting this information, you're doing nothing to help the situation.

Comment: @Dumbassahedratron It would appear you might need a refresher of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in addition to reading the links I provided in the comment above.  Don't take it personally.  I'm just trying to help

Comment: If you were trying to help, you'd exert more effort in doing so beyond linking general practices. Evidently, they contain an element of ambiguity. Also, seems like a bit of a cop-out to make a claim then not provide anything to back it up. It should be more than apparent I'm willing to fix the question if given the opportunity, but I'm not gonna sit here and make revisions a la high school essay just to appease your standards of what a question should look like.

Comment: @MickyD also, second link: `comment and explain why their question is bad and how to fix it, use the tour, the help, maybe even a chat session`